# Android - Customizing Dialog using an Xml Layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, dialog

I am trtying to create this layout below, but I can seem to get the right 
layout that I need. What I'm trying to accomplish is have a customize dailog box,
using a layout. I tried edit the xml below but if this is shown as a dialog the 
defined layout is a mess. Please help me understand what I need to do for
this. THanks and looking forward. They dialog is SHOWING but the layout is not met.

This layout is what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

Dialog:

```
View checkBoxView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.display_item_dialog, null);
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
       // Save to shared preferences
     }   
});
checkBox.setText("Search All Images");
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Image Preferences");
builder.setMessage(" Select from below ")
.setView(checkBoxView)
.setCancelable(false)
.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    }
})
.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
}).show();
```

display_item_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Map Category: BEVERAGES" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sunny" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:text="+" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:text="-" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:clickable="false" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Map Category: BEVERAGES" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="+" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:clickable="false" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="-" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: if there is still an issue then put the whole layout in `ScrollView`.

Comment: Sir, as what you have suggested to use ScrollView, but it is not working. Can you check if scrollview is possible in this layout?

Comment: explain *not working*. I have placed it in `ScrollView`, check answer now.

Comment: How do you get click events if it is defined in the XML?

Comment: You have to set click listener in java code, `android:onClick` only works with activities as far as I know.

Answer (score 9):

You can refer to this tutorials

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

```
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        dialog.setTitle("Title...");

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
```

Comment: hi! I added the desired layout above. I am bit concern right now with the desired xml layout sir Nirali.

Comment: Means you are not able to set your XML view like what you want as per image?

Comment: The image above is the one that I need to have in displaying my dialog or dialog should look the same as the image above. I need to work with the xml sir.

Comment: Why do official Android docs say that.. "Dialog class is the base class for dialogs, but you should avoid instantiating Dialog directly. Instead, use one of the following subclasses.." [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html] ???