# How to make the switch button center in dialog

Tags: android, button, dialog, switch-statement, center

I want to switch button center in dialog,but it's failed...

Why is this?

```
Switch sw = new Switch(MainActivity.this);
sw.setTextOn("start");
sw.setTextOff("close");
sw.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
myDialog.setTitle("title");
myDialog.setMessage("message");
myDialog.setView(sw);
```

[image]

Comment: Use a Layout in your dialog.

Comment: In this way, it can not achieve?

Comment: Maybe it will help you : [Android - Customizing Dialog using an Xml Layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486409/android-customizing-dialog-using-an-xml-layout)

Comment: use `LayoutParams` for the view.

Comment: Thanks,I can try it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with below code

```
        Switch sw = new Switch(MainActivity.this);
        sw.setTextOn("start");
        sw.setTextOff("close");


        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        linearLayout.addView(sw);


        AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = new    AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        myDialog.setTitle("title");
        myDialog.setMessage("message");
        myDialog.setView(linearLayout);


        myDialog.show();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the way I need

Answer (score 3):

Use the `custom_layout` instead.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

           <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Use `LayoutInflater` to inflate the layout in dialog

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
myDialog.setView(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout instead, set android:centerInParent=true for SwitchButton